# sconfig - access is denied - server 2012r2 core on hyperv

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-core

I have a vm on hyperv (host is running server 2012r2) running server 2012r2 core.
Its been working fine for months, today I can no longer run sconfig to manage it locally.
I type sconfig, the command window flashes blue like its about to load then goes back to the command prompt with an access is denied message.
I've taken ownership of sconfig.vbs and assigned permissions so I am owner and have rights to it.

takeown /f c:\Windows\System32\en-US\sconfig.vbs
icacls c:\Windows\System32\en-US\sconfig.vbs /grant username:f

still get the same error.

How can I check what the error is to fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, Have any GPOs been applied recently that might have denied access to SCONFIG?

Comment: Hi Michael.  No new GPO's have been applied but I can check.  Which settings in particular would cause this?

Comment: Maybe a Software Restriction Policy, its only an initial thought.

Answer (score 0):

I couldnt find the problem but was able to use the windows update module for powershell to do what I wanted - install updates.
Looks like a problem with the vbs file rather than permissions or unintended gpo restrictions.